# what memory settings should I use for eclipse on this system?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, memory, jvm

I need to run my program in eclipse and i was hoping to speed up the process by increasing the memory size of eclipse but i'm confused about which settings to use.

this is my system:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: MacBookAir3,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  1.86 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
```

and this is my current eclipse .ini:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1536m
-Xmx1536m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

What should I use at XX, Xms and Xmx?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use those

-server -Xms3g -Xmx3g -Xmn1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -   XX:ThreadStackSize=2048 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+UseNUMA -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

That's it)

Comment: Seriously? He's running on a 4g machine, and you suggest he starts Eclipse with 3g Xms?... That won't work out so well unless you're not running ANYTHING else on that machine.

Comment: you are right - then those options should be better for performance -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Xmn256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m - XX:ThreadStackSize=2048 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

Answer (score 0):

Those memory settings are for running the Eclipse IDE, not necessarily the program you're coding on it.

For that you can set specific -Xms and -Xmx values at the Run Configuration of your program.

As to the values... it depends solely on your program, so there's no "one size fits all".

Regarding the Eclipse params, your Xmx might be ok, but I would lower the Xms quite a bit, to 256m or so.

Xms is basically the starting memory size allocated when the program runs, Xmx is the maximum. starting out with 1.5gigs seems a bit excessive.